# Blazor app loads boostrap-dark.css file twice

Tags: blazor

using Blazor with dotnet core 3.1 and having strange issue that boostrap-dark.css is loaded twice when accessing homepage...

if you look in network anlysis, you can see it:
[image]

I'm loading the HTML Header area partially dynamic within _Host.cshtml you can see that HtmlHeadComponent is rendered:

```
@page "/"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/main.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage/protectedBrowserStorage.js">        </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js">    </script>
    <script src="~/js/my.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ej2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ejs.interop.min.js"></script>

    <component type="typeof(HtmlHeadComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The HtmlHeadComponent.razor file has the following code:

```
@inject AppState  AppState

@if (Store != null)
{
    <title>@Store.MetaTitleDerived</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Store.FavIconUrlDerived">

    <meta name="description" content="@Store.MetaDescription" />    
    <meta name="keywords" content="@Store.MetaKeywords" />
    <meta name="author" content="@Store.MetaAuthor" />
    <meta name="robots" content="@Store.MetaRobots" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/@Store.BaseCssFilename" />
}

@code {
    public Db_Store Store => AppState?.StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Store == null)
        {
            AppState.StoreData = await AppState.GetStoreData(My.StoreId);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me where the problem is?
Is it a Blazor bug or do I anything wrong?

THx!

Comment: Can you inspect the page and share the rendered HTML?

Comment: A component can be rendered multiple time,so each time it is rendered your css is going to be downloaded

Comment: I would right click the page and click `View Page Source` and see if the link is there twice, and investigate from there.